# Spring Data JPA query by discriminator type

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to create a Sping Data JPA repository method that finds an Entity by the discriminator type, among other properties.

I've read the Spring Data JPA documentation and searched here for an answer to this question but couldn't find it.

Take for instance these classes:

```
public class DynamicAttribute {

    String label;
    DynamicType dynamicType;
}

public abstract class DynamicType {...}
```

`DynamicType` is extended by a few classes.

The method I need in the `DynamicAttributeRepository` would be something like this:

```
Optional<DynamicAttribute> findByLabelAndDynamicType(String label, Class<? extends DynamicType> dynamicType);
```

However it doesn't work. If I pass a PersonType.class (PersonType extends DynamicType) as the second parameter and doesn't find any results and says that "PersonType" is not of the expected type "DynamicType".

Could anyone please help?

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" needs more clarification, or this will get closed soon.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for inheritance: https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/cmp30cfg016.htm

Comment: @kab Inheritance is already configured. Still not working.